# Host a subdomain in Azure DNS and the domain in webs.com

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, domain, subdomain

**What I have:**

- A domain purchased in webs.com (I'll call it contoso.com);
- A main website hosted in webs.com using contoso.com as dns (I didn't build and configure it by myself);
- A second website (its purpose is to expose a new service offered by my company) hosted throught an Azure VM using IIS as web server;

**What I want:**

I would like to create a subdomain (e.g. sub.contoso.com) and link it with my second website. If possible, I wouldn't want to transfer the main website in Azure (it would be too time consuming and expensive at the moment) or the second website in webs.com (it's impossible) or buy a second domain.

**What I've done:**

To accomplish this I followed step by step this guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/delegate-subdomain

**The problem:**

The problem is that the "Test the delegation" step fail.

I'm not sure but I think that the problem is due to the Name Server list in webs.com. In fact here I found two Name Servers inserted by default by webs.com and, since they are necessary for the proper functioning of the main website, I only added the 4 Azure Name Servers.

I wrote to webs.com about this issue and they told me that at the moment it's not possible have the main web site hosted by them and a subdomain hosted by Azure.

Is there a workaround? For exemple, create an A record in Azure to link the main website and removing the 2 default Name Servers in webs.com

Comment: Tthe "workaround" you suggest is the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks! A second question: what IP address I have to use for the A record in Azure? The command `nslookup contoso.com` return to me 5 different IPv4 addresses. I have to use all of them?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.